# Custom Login Page for Spring Boot + Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

Below is my configuration.  I navigate to http://localhost:8080 and is redirected to http://localhost:8080/bruceLogin which is expected. But i got page displaying "Whitelabel Error Page. This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback...".
Note I did have a simple html page called bruceLogin1.html under src/main/resources/template.
Any idea what i am missing here?

*Side Note: One sad thing is that spring boot does not provide a mechanism for developer to configure the custom login page using solely properties file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityCatalogApplication  implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityCatalogApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/bruceLogin").setViewName("bruceLogin1");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

             http
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/bruceLogin")
             .permitAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need configure ViewResolvers by override method  @Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp().prefix("/WEB-INF/views/").suffix(".jsp");
}

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply. But I am using html, not jsp. In addition, My current html is located in src/main/resources/template, and i thought by default spring security + spring boot should already automatically configure this "src/main/resources/template" path to be the prefix

Comment: Moreover, i follow https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html#configuring-a-custom-login-page, and the guide never mention anything about overriding configureViewResolvers method.  

*Do note that one main difference is that my solution uses "implement WebMvcConfigurer", but the article uses "extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter".  I did not follow the latter, cos WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is already deprecated, and the recommendation is to use the "implement WebMvcConfigurer".

Comment: Please add .antMatchers("/bruceLogin").permitAll() on the top as following code:
http
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/bruceLogin").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/bruceLogin")
             .permitAll();

Comment: If you use html: Have you imported thymeleaf into your project? Sometimes this does the trick...

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the advise. I try adding .antMatchers("/bruceLogin"), it doesn't work. Still same error. I will give the thymeleaf import a try, although my html does not contain any thymeleaf syntax. Will update my result here again once i tried it out.

Comment: Hi Pham Thai Thinh, it works, after i import thymeleaf! Thanks. 
But if my intention is to just serve static html page, does that mean i am forced to import thymeleaf?

Comment: I think I know why i need to import thymeleaf. This is because any view returns by controller need a view resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: This issue is resolved after I add implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf' to my build.gradle. Thanks to Pham Thai Thinh for the suggestion